# Can't access element's class to change its name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, toggle

I'd like to change an element's class from **score -box1** to **score -box1.-active**. I created a const $target to try to access the class score -box1 but its not working.

```
const $target = document.getElementByClassname('score -box1')
function PlayerScore(score = 0){
    if(score == 1){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }else if(score == 2){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }else if(score == 3){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }

    return( /*html*/
    `
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "score -box1">one</div>
            <div class = "score -box2">two</div>
            <div class = "score -box3">three</div>
        </div>
    `
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do the boxes have class `box[n]` at all? If you want to differentiate between them a data attribute is probably the better option.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very React-ive way to go about this in the first place. You usually shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using React, this is the wrong approach. React has its own way of updating the DOM. jQuery will just get in the way, and you won't get the results you want. You should be using state to help update the element classes. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @Andy, I agree, but if this is intended to be jQuery it won't work anyway. jQuery can't act on native elements with methods like `toggle()`.

Comment: OP, if you could add in the rest of your component to your question, and add some details of what causes the classList to be updated, we can probably guide to you to a better solution.

Comment: @isherwood sure it can, if the actual jquery method was being called on them.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm not sure I get your point. As it's written above [it won't work](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rsq1en0b).

Comment: @isherwood Yes, however, `toggle` in that case isn't jQuery's toggle method. it simply isn't a function at all.

Comment: Yep. We get that. The issue was the implication that it was _possibly_ jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The proper method is `.querySelectorAll` and it returns a node list , if you add a `[0]` at the end like below, you will get the first element of that  node list (which maybe what you want for now), but if you want all target elements use a `for loop` to loop over `document.querySelectorAll('score -box1')` array.

```
const $target = document.querySelectorAll('score -box1')[0]
function PlayerScore(score = 0){
    if(score == 1){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }else if(score == 2){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }else if(score == 3){
        $target.toggle('-active');
    }

    return( /*html*/
    `
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "score -box1">one</div>
            <div class = "score -box2">two</div>
            <div class = "score -box3">three</div>
        </div>
    `
    )
}
```

Or you can replace the `.querySelectorAll` with with `.querySelector`, it will automatically rturn the first element: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: If you use `querySelector` you won't have to grab the first element like that.